# Why Tcl expr does not equal 2 true boolean values?

Tags: tcl

I have this script:

```
$ cat tmp/bool.tcl
puts "[expr [expr True] == [expr true] ]"
```

I expect it prints 1 because both "True" and "true" are boolean true so they should equal, but I get 0:

```
$ tclsh tmp/bool.tcl
0
```

Of course this is simplified code. The real code generates boolean values in string, "True", "true", "Yes", "yEs", etc.

Do I have to make them all lower case before comparing them?

I do not understand why the above code does not equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`==` operator](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/mathop.htm#M14) is **defined** to do (the documentation in the `expr` page itself is more obscure):

> numeric comparison if possible, exact string comparison otherwise

Neither `True` nor `true` is numeric, so exact string comparison is used. The two values differ in the first character of their string representation; they are therefore not equal in the sense of `==`.

To compare uncontrolled boolean values for equality, invert them first as the result of the `!` operator is both boolean and numeric (i.e., it's 0 or 1):

```
set a Yes
set b tRuE
expr {!$a == !$b}
```

Comment: I'd use the following, direct test: `expr {$a && $b}`.

Answer (score 3):

```
% puts "[expr [expr True] == [expr true] ]"
0
```

Let's look at what each side does:

```
% expr True
True
% expr true
true
```

So, both recognized as boolean values, but not equal. Let's convert those strings to a "canonical" boolean form:

```
% set a True
True
% set b true
true
% expr {$a == $b}
0
% expr {!!$a == !!$b}
1
```

What's going on here: step-by-step

```
% expr {$a}
True
% expr {!$a}
0
% expr {!!$a}
1
```

The native "true/false" values are "1/0" respectively. And clearly `1 == 1`

Opinion: this feels like it goes back to Tcl's "everything is a string" roots, and the strings "True" and "true" are unequal.

Comment: Implicit in my answer: 1) you don't need to nest `expr` calls; 2) [brace your expressions](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Brace+your+expr-essions)

Comment: There are a few cases where nesting `expr` makes sense. This is not one of them.